# Using vs-threading in asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Is there any problems with using the Analyzers and the Primitives in the vs-threading project in a asp.net project?

vs-threading: https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading

Comment: There is an Issues tab in their GitHub project which should tell you about any known problems.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yep, looked and searched for asp.net but did not find anything. However since the project is tagged with ui-thread it raises the question.

Comment: So... you didn't find any issues. Doesn't that answer your question then?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Just because there are no reported issues for asp.net in that relatively unkown repo (295 stars) used for developing Visual Studio itself, i'd figured SO would be the place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VSTHRD200](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD200.md) may not be a good fit if your controller methods are async but you don't want Async as a suffix to those methods because that would influence the public URLs.
[VSTHRD012](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD012.md) may not apply either, since you probably don't have a JoinableTaskFactory in an ASP.NET environment.

A couple of others may not apply ([VSTHRD001](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD001.md) and [VSTHRD003](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD003.md)), but they won't likely produce diagnostics in that context either so not so much of an issue.